# Login hangs forever

Tags: login, login-screen

I'm on Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS

I've just installed the latest updates and restarted my computer. I can get to the login screen, but after I put in my password, it does not proceed. No error, no freeze, just a looping cursor.

I `Ctrl+Alt+F2` into a TTY login. It also waits forever, and eventually kicks me back to enter my username. It doesn't matter if I leave it empty or fill it with junk, same result.

This is not the first time this has happened. I don't know what happens to fix it, and I don't know why it starts again. I don't restart my computer often, only when an update requires a restart. I have a Dell Precision 3541. It came with Ubuntu already installed

Answer (score 0):

When you have a login that takes forever, and you're sure it's the password that's taking a long time, a good place to look is in `/var/log/auth.log`.

I kept seeing `fingerprint-helper` and `pam_fingerprint-gui` consistently with error messages. I think I installed them in the hope I could get my fingerprint scanner on my laptop to start working. Well, they must've been blocking password authentication, because I can log in instantly after `apt remove`-ing those packages.